# Accessing SMSESSION value in a Java Application

Tags: java, siteminder

We have a Java desktop application that makes SOA Web Service requests to some backend services that require SMSESSION value passed into the SOAP Headers.  In our Web Application we get Single-Sign-On once SMSESSION is established in a browser Cookie, so passing SMSESSION is seamless.

For our Desktop application we don't know how to get SMSESSION from the desktop.  Is there an SiteMinder Java API that would allow for us to grab SMSESSION from a cookie on the desktop or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

The [Class SmAuthenticationContext](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/javadoc-sm/com/netegrity/policyserver/smapi/SmAuthenticationContext.html) contains methods which:

- lets you retrieve an AppSpecificContext object
- includes credentials information from the user directory where user context was established
- sets the user text response for this authentication request

Here are a few references which may help:

- [CA SiteMinder API Reference Guide for Java](http://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/javadoc-sm/overview-summary.html)
- [Persistence Service](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/jdk/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#PersistenceService)
- [NTLM SSO](https://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/NTLM+SSO)
- [Simplify enterprise Java authentication with single sign-on](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gss-sso/)